# Why are edited instances of recurrent events listed when using singleEvents=false in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I created one recurrent event, repeats for 3 days.

Then when I search using:

```
calendarService.events().list("primary").setTimeMin(min).setTimeMax(max).setSingleEvents(false).setShowDeleted(false).execute();
```

I get only the underlying recurrent event:

```
Event ID: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro 
Summary: Google Calendar API test event 
Status: confirmed 
Event Start/End: {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T15:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"} {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T16:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"}
Recurrence: [RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3]
RecurringEventId: null
```

So far so good, but when I edit (through Google Calendar web page) only one of the recurrences, and repeat the same previous search, I also get the edited event (the second one, you can see I changed the summary):

```
Event ID: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro 
Summary: Google Calendar API test event 
Status: confirmed 
Event Start/End: {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T15:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"} {"dateTime":"2017-05-17T16:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"}
Recurrence: [RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3]
RecurringEventId: null

Event ID: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro_20170518T132453Z 
Summary: foo bar Google Calendar API test event  
Status: confirmed 
Event Start/End: {"dateTime":"2017-05-18T15:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"} {"dateTime":"2017-05-18T16:24:53.000+02:00","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin"}
Recurrence: null
RecurringEventId: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro
```

Why I get an instance of recurrent event in a query with `setSingleEvents(false)` after the instance is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Haven't found docs that explicitly explains the behavior of calendar events, but basing from the details you provided and the parameter's description:

> Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is False.

If an instance of a recurring event is modified, it would be treated as *different than the usual* recurring event (i.e. *single one-off event*), making the `Recurrence` null, which I presume is parameter that is checked if an event is eligible to be returned for `singleEvents` and the `RecurringEventId` is used to trace from which recurring event it was originally from.

Comment: Hi @AL., not sure I agree with that. As you can see, the modified instance still points to the parent event because it still has the attribute RecurringEventId: cq61agdr4sbdnfj7rfbpbk2pro. The Recurrence attribute, is only mantained by the parent (underlying recurrent event, as per Google Docs), this attribute holds recurrence information.

Comment: Hey Robson. I see. However, the behavior still kinda remains, where *modified* events seem to become non-recurring events and *tagged* as a separate one-off event themselves. With that said, still couldn't find any official docs that discuss it tho. Cheers!